# File reading in hexa editor

Tags: binary, numbers, hex, number-systems

I am a bit curious about the file system and how a file is written in a disk.
I have written `23` in a file.

[image]

While opening this file in hex editor, I found this like below

[image]

Why the hex editor is showing the file this way? I am curious to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. 
In the hex editor, it shows the ASCII Hex value for the character.

What happens while writing a text file, corresponding ASCII value is written in binary.

Here, in my text editor, the value is 23.

> ASCII Decimal value of 2 is `50`, ASCII hexaDecimal value is `32` and
>   ASCII  Binary is `110010`
>
> ASCII Decimal value of 3 is `51`, ASCII hexaDecimal value is `33` and
>   ASCII  Binary is `110011`

In the file, the binary value is written. But, As I open the file with a hex editor, it is showing the hex ASCII value of the corresponding character.